# Does fast enumeration evaluate the collection expression on every iteration?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

If I have the following piece of code:

```
        for (UIView *view in [myArray copy])
```

Does that mean that I'm sending the `copy` message to `myArray` on every iteration, or Objective-C is smart enough to do `copy` only once, and use it for the whole loop?

Comment: Not hard to explain at all. You asked this question very clearly!

Comment: The answer is that `copy` is only executed once.  The expression on the right is evaluated before the `in` operation is initiated.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882254/objective-c-for-each-fast-enumeration-evaluation-of-collection or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281461/is-this-an-inefficient-way-of-using-fast-enumeration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a matter of "smart", but yes, the expression `[myArray copy]` is evaluated once up front.